# "Mean average precision" (MAP) evaluation statistic - understanding good/bad/chance values

Tags: information-retrieval, multilabel, average-precision

I'm evaluating a multilabel classifier. I'm familiar with the Area Under the Curve statistic, which has some nice properties (e.g. chance level is always 50%). But for some applications, it's more appropriate to use the **"Mean average precision"** metric which evaluates results based on the top $K$ results returned. MAP is described nicely [here at fastml](http://fastml.com/what-you-wanted-to-know-about-mean-average-precision/) and [here at kaggle](http://www.kaggle.com/c/FacebookRecruiting/forums/t/2002/alternate-explanation-of-mean-average-precision). In my case I'm using MAP@20, so evaluation is on the top 20 results returned. (My data contains a variable number of true-positive labels for each item, up to 12.)

But: what is a good score for MAP@20? What is a bad score? What is the chance score?

(Clearly 100% is the best score and 0% is the worst.)

I can't find an online reference that discusses this. I think the chance score must depend on the ratio of positive to negative labels in your data.

It would also be helpful to know if there's a useful interpretion of the score. For AUC there's an interpretation as the probability of ranking a random positive instance higher than a random negative instance. Grateful for references or explanations.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for what it's worth, here is an empirical plot of the chance values for the MAP statistic. In this plot, the x axis represents the proportion of ground-truth-positives in the data, and the y axis represents how far we go down the ranked list when evaluating MAP.

[image: matrix plot - fades down to 20%, 10% or lower as the num positives in groundtruth increase]

The [code to produce the plot is here](https://gist.github.com/danstowell/10174964).

Answer (score 0):

For this part of the question "What is the chance score?...", you could look at this paper: Exact Expected Average Precision of the Random Baseline for System Evaluation, The Prague Bulletin of Mathematical Linguistics, 2015, 103, 131–138 (https://ufal.mff.cuni.cz/pbml/103/art-bestgen.pdf).